# How to crop an image in an electron application

Tags: image, electron, crop, electron-builder

In Electron 4.0 sharp does not work (https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1522), imagemagick output "Error: spawn identify ENOENT", Jimp gives an error with markers or other.

The method with the canvas problem with async or with a buffer, outputs the image pieces.

Are there any other options? Is there anyone in the electron does it work?